# Dropdown item insert between two list items using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have radio button and dropdown like this:

**Dropdown**

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTravelType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" EnableViewState="false" onclick="TypeOfTravelOnChange('rblTypeOfTravel');">
        <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="Air Travel"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="O" Text="Other Travel"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Radio button**

```
<select name="DrTravelMode" id="DrTravelMode">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="A">Air</option>
    <option value="T">Bus</option>
    <option value="B">train</option>
<select>
```

**script :**

```
function TypeOfTravelOnChange(RadioButtonId) {
if ($('input:radio[name=' + RadioButtonId + ']:checked').val() == 'O') {
 $("#DrTravelMode option[value='A']").remove(); 
}
else
{
 // here i want to append the dropdown value "Air" between --Select-- and Bus
}
```

}

My question is , how to insert a new list item between two items using **javascript**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the below script in else block, it's work fine..

```
var select = document.getElementById("DrTravelMode");
    if ($("#DrTravelMode option[value='A']").length == 0) {
        var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
        opt2.text = "Air";
        opt2.value = "A";
        select.add(opt2, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

You need to find the index and then use as follows

```
$("select option").eq(index).before($("<option></option>").val(val).html(text));
```

In your case

Find the index first as follows

```
var index= $("#DrTravelMode option[value='A']").index()
```

then delete and then add at the above index

Comment: $("select option").eq(2).before($("<option></option>").val('A').html('Air')); not worked this..